# Chromedp - how to get image file size and real dimensions

Tags: chromedp

I am trying to retrieve some information like page load time, first paint but also the images and scripts that are being loaded and their sizes.

I am able to detect everything that is being loaded in terms of images and scripts but when I look at the sizes, they do not match the size which I see in my (Firefox) inspector.

Can anyone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

I would also like to get to know how long it took to load the specific file.

I came up with this code. This shows me the correct name and mimetype, but as said, the file size is not correct.

```
chromedp.ListenTarget(ctx, func(ev interface{}) {
   switch ev := ev.(type) {

   case *network.EventResponseReceived:
      eventResponseReceived = append(eventResponseReceived, network.EventResponseReceived{
         RequestID:    ev.RequestID,
         LoaderID:     ev.LoaderID,
         Timestamp:    ev.Timestamp,
         Type:         ev.Type,
         Response:     ev.Response,
         HasExtraInfo: ev.HasExtraInfo,
         FrameID:      ev.FrameID,
      })

   case *network.EventLoadingFinished:
      eventLoadingFinished = append(eventLoadingFinished, network.EventLoadingFinished{
         RequestID:                ev.RequestID,
         Timestamp:                ev.Timestamp,
         EncodedDataLength:        ev.EncodedDataLength,
         ShouldReportCorbBlocking: ev.ShouldReportCorbBlocking,
      })
   }

})

for i := range eventResponseReceived {
    for i2 := range eventLoadingFinished {
        if eventResponseReceived[i].RequestID == eventLoadingFinished[i2].RequestID {
            fmt.Println(eventResponseReceived[i].Response.URL)
            fmt.Println(eventResponseReceived[i].Response.ResponseTime.Time())
            fmt.Println(eventResponseReceived[i2].Response.EncodedDataLength)
            fmt.Println(eventResponseReceived[i].Response.MimeType)
        }
    }
}
```

I found out that I, in some cases, can get the content-length. But for a lot of files the content-length unfortunately is nil.

`eventResponseReceived[i2].Response.Headers["content-length"]`

So for the files where no content-length was given, I need a solution.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to measure the response size and the load time. In this case, I think you should check both the [Network.responseReceived](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-responseReceived) event and the [Network.loadingFinished](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-loadingFinished) event. (The corresponding events in chromedp are `network.EventResponseReceived` and `network.EventLoadingFinished`).

I have attached an example request to the end of this answer. I will try to answer the question based on this example request.

#### Size

It's correct to get the size from the `Network.loadingFinished` event. Please note that this is not the file size. It's the **total number of bytes received for this request**. And it could be 0 if the response is loaded from a cache. The following fields from the `response` field of the `Network.responseReceived` event would tell you why `encodedDataLength` is 0 (an example event has been attached, read it first):

- `fromDiskCache`: specifies that the request was served from the disk cache.
- `fromServiceWorker`: specifies that the request was served from the ServiceWorker.
- `fromPrefetchCache`: specifies that the request was served from the prefetch cache.

Don't try to read `encodedDataLength` from the `response` field. Because it's  just the **total number of bytes received for this request so far**. There could be more data to receive (reported by the [Network.dataReceived](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-dataReceived) events, see the screenshot).

And don't try to read the size from the `Content-Length` header. It's not always provided, and it's not correct to use it to measure network payload.

#### Time

I will try to list the metrics in the timing tab (see the screenshot) based on my try and test. If not specified, the data points are from the `response.timing` field of the `Network.responseReceived` event.

- Stalled: `dnsStart`. It a connection is reused, it could be `sendStart`.
- DNS Lookup: `DnsEnd` - `DnsStart`.
- Initial connection: `connectEnd` - `connectStart`
- SSL: `sslEnd` - `sslStart`
- Request sent: `sendEnd` - `sendStart`
- Waiting for server response: `receiveHeadersEnd` - `sendEnd`
- Content Download: `timestamp` (from the `Network.loadingFinished` event) - `requestTime` - `receiveHeadersEnd`.

I think you want to check the **Waiting for server response** metric and the **Content Download** metric most of the time.

#### Recommentation

[Protocol Monitor](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#monitor) is a must-have tool if you want to work with Chrome DevTools Protocol.

#### Example Request

See the screenshot below:
[image: screenshot of DevTools console]

Here is the `Network.responseReceived` event (some fields are removed):

```json
{
  "requestId": "580832.38",
  "timestamp": 40037.455632,
  "type": "Image",
  "response": {
    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/noIxfDrKx_Q/maxresdefault.jpg",
    "status": 200,
    "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
    "connectionReused": false,
    "fromDiskCache": false,
    "fromServiceWorker": false,
    "fromPrefetchCache": false,
    "encodedDataLength": 55,
    "timing": {
      "requestTime": 40036.989753,
      "proxyStart": -1,
      "proxyEnd": -1,
      "dnsStart": 0.662,
      "dnsEnd": 81.792,
      "connectStart": 81.792,
      "connectEnd": 332.482,
      "sslStart": 158.76,
      "sslEnd": 332.473,
      "workerStart": -1,
      "workerReady": -1,
      "workerFetchStart": -1,
      "workerRespondWithSettled": -1,
      "sendStart": 332.906,
      "sendEnd": 333.142,
      "pushStart": 0,
      "pushEnd": 0,
      "receiveHeadersEnd": 459.986
    },
    "responseTime": 1668830468734.381
  },
  "frameId": "83262FAD65C24B78F2B7E6F884B2B146"
}
```

And here is the `Network.loadingFinished` event:

```json
{
  "requestId": "580832.38",
  "timestamp": 40037.577265,
  "encodedDataLength": 50766,
  "shouldReportCorbBlocking": false
}
```